# Encoding error using Python

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters

I wrote a code to connect to imap and then parse the body information and insert into database. But I am having some problems with accents.

From email header I got this information:

> Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

But, I am not sure if I can trust in this information...

The email was wrote in portuguese, so we have a lot of words with accents. For example, I extract the following phrase from the email source code (using my browser):

> "...instalação de eletrônicos..."

So, I connected to imap and fetched some emails:

> ... typ, data = M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)') ...

When I print the content, I get the following word:

```
print data[0][1]
```

> ```
> instala+º+úo de eletr+¦nicos
> ```

I tried to use `.decode('utf-8')` but I had no success.

> instalaÃ§Ã£o de eletrÃ´nicos

How can I make it a human readable? My database is in utf-8.

Comment: What does `print(type(data[0][1])); print(repr(data[0][1]))` print?

Comment: @WinstonEwert - Python 2.7

Comment: @MartijnPieters - type: <type 'str'> and "print(repr(" returned accents with the following format: fun\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o (sorry, this is another accented word)

Comment: No, that's *exactly* what I wanted to see. That's `função` in UTF8. And `.decode('utf8')` should work, perhaps you need to show us more code?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I tried: print repr(data[0][1]).decode('utf8') but still showing "fun\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o" (you are right about decoded word "função")

Comment: You decoded the `repr()`; remove the `repr()` there... That is the *wrong* thing to decode! :-P Also note that `print` will use your *terminal encoding* to try to encode your `unicode` value to something your terminal can actually display. That *can* fail (especially on Windows).

Comment: In any case, you need to read the [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24336/discussion-between-thomas-bryan-and-martijn-pieters)

Answer (score 0):

The header says it is using "ISO-8859-1" charset. So you need to decode the string with that encoding.

Try this:

```
data[0][1].decode('iso-8859-1')
```

Comment: That would not lead to the double bytes seen by the OP. Let's see what my request for the type and repr of the data gives us, shall we?

Comment: It returned the following error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\x83' in position 20: character maps to <undefined>

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the source code encoding worked for me. It's the code at the top of my example code below. This should be defined at the top of your python file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-

value = """...instalação de eletrônicos...""".decode("iso-8859-15")
print value
# prints: ...instalação de eletrônicos...

import unicodedata
value = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', value).encode('ascii','ignore')
print value
# prints: ...instalacao de eletronicos...
```

And now you can do str(value) without an exception as well.

See: http://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html

This seems to keep all accents:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-
import unicodedata
value = """...instalação de eletrônicos...""".decode("iso-8859-15")
value = unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', value).encode('utf-8')
print value
print str(value)

# prints (without exceptions/errors):
# ...instalação de eletrônicos...
# ...instalação de eletrônicos...
```

**EDIT:**

Do note that with the last version even though the outcome looks the same it doesn't return equal is True. In example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-
import unicodedata
inValue = """...instalação de eletrônicos...""".decode("iso-8859-15")
normalizedValue = unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', inValue).encode('utf-8')

try:
    print inValue == normalizedValue
except UnicodeWarning:
    pass
# False
```

**EDIT2:**

This returns the same:

```
normalizedValue = unicode("""...instalação de eletrônicos...""".decode("iso-8859-15")).encode('utf-8')
print normalizedValue 
print str(normalizedValue )

# prints (without exceptions/errors):
# ...instalação de eletrônicos...
# ...instalação de eletrônicos...
```

Though I'm not sure this will actually be valid for a utf-8 encoded database. Probably not?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Martijn Pieters. We figured out that the email had two different encode. I had to split this parts and treat individually.